# esacping single quotes while using egrep in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I need to find  some special characters in a given input string .
If the string contains following special characters it should find out.
i am doing  egrep to find the characters.
My code is working for every character but not single quotes.
please find my code snippet.

```
splCharCheck='egrep "&|\"|:|\'" | wc -l'

count=`echo  "$Name" | eval $splCharCheck`
```

Can any one help me how to escape single quotes here?

Answer (score 0):

Don't "escape" the single quote. Check below:

```
# cat test
'name with quotes'
no quotes

# cat test | egrep "'"
'name with quotes'

# cat test | egrep "\'"
'name with quotes'
no quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve? This smells like an XY problem.

In bash you can escape text easily using

```
printf "%q\n" "$Name"
```

E.g.:

```
$ Name="Some 'intricate' value"
$ printf "%q\n" "$Name"
Some\ \'intricate\'\ value
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to embed a single-quote inside a double-quoted string which is inside a single-quoted string. The problem is that inside the single-quoted string, the double-quotes aren't treated as anything special, so the single-quote in the middle gets treated as the end of the single-quoted string rather than a part of it. In order to do this, you need to end the single-quoted string (`'egrep "&|\"|:|'`), escape the lone single-quote some other way (either `\'` or `"'"`), then start a new single-quoted string with the rest of what you want (`'" | wc -l'`). End result:

```
splCharCheck='egrep "&|\"|:|'\''" | wc -l'
```

However, I have to agree with @sehe that it looks like you're trying to solve the wrong problem. Why are you putting this command in a variable rather than executing it directly? That's [generally a bad idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (and `eval` just adds more opportunities for things to get weird). And, backing up even further, what are you really trying to do?

p.s. If you must use `eval`, at least double-quote the string your're eval'ing. Failing to do this can lead to some seriously incomprehensible errors. Finally, I recommend using `$( )` instead of backquotes, since it has fewer parsing oddities:

```
count=$(echo  "$Name" | eval "$splCharCheck")
```